# Does the Administrator determine the default column views?

Tags: sharepoint-views

I am using SharePoint 2013.

My question is, does the SharePoint Administrator determine which column views display when a new App is created within SharePoint?

If this is the case, can the Administrator allow certain column views to display for different apps created? For instance, if I create a new task list, can the default column views be different from the default column views of a document library?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The default view for all templates are predefined by Microsoft. When adding new columns, the last options asks if you would like to add the new column in the default view. Check that box and the column will be added.

If you need to create specific libraries or list with default columns in a view, create a list with the columns that you need (with them added to the default view) and save it as a list template. Or just change the view without adding any columns, save as a template and then hide the original list templates and use your own.